# CSS - Making draggable custom list item responsive

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-ui

I have a pretty extensive program in which I have:

```
<ul>
  <li class="courseBox">...lots of content...</li>
  <li class="courseBox">...lots of content...</li>
  <li class="courseBox">...lots of content...</li>
</ul>
```

All of my "courseBox" elements are draggable elements and the `<ul>`s are the droppable items. The courseBoxes are added to the  by using javascript and they are responsive at first. However when dragging the `<li>` to another `<ul>` it stops being responsive. Does anyone know what the problem could be?

The only styling used on the courseBox is the following:

```
.courseBox {
  position: relative;
  border: thin solid #999;
  padding-top: 5px;
  padding-left: 5px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;

  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(firebrick, darkred); /* For Safari 5.1   to 6.0 */
  background: -o-linear-gradient(firebrick, darkred); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(firebrick, darkred); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(firebrick, darkred);
  background: linear-gradient(firebrick, darkred); /* Standard syntax */

  color: #fff;
  cursor: move;
}
```

I created this small [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8g2oqp0h/40/) to illustrate the problem.

Thanks in advance..

Comment: You mean the `li` contains immediately to the top of the `ul` without the effect?

Comment: because when you drag the li to another ul > li it gives inline style to dropped li, check in the firebug, it add style(width: 586px; right: auto; height: 82px; bottom: auto; left: 0px; top: 0px;)(may be vary) to li. which make it un-responsive.

Comment: @Patrick2607. No. I mean when the web page is resized after having moved the `<li>`, it no longer scales to the full width of the `<ul>`

@RanjeetSingh. Do you know a good way around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just change `css-width` of `dropped` element to `auto` on `drop` option of `.semester`.

Here it is:

```
$(".semester").droppable({
    accept: ".courseBox",
    activeClass: "highlight",
    drop: function(ev, ui) {
        var dropped = ui.draggable;
        var droppedOn = $(this);

        $(dropped).detach().css({
            top: 0,
            left: 0
        }).appendTo(droppedOn).css('width', "auto"); //this here
    }
});
```

Same goes with `drop` option of `.basket - droppable`

## [`DEMO HERE`](https://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/8g2oqp0h/42/)

Comment: Anytime.. Happy coding.. :)